# Why do some french people inappropriately add an 'h' before English words starting with 'a' or 'e'?

Tags: prononciation

I've heard a few french people adding an 'h' when pronouncing English words starting with an 'a' or an 'e'. The word 'and' is pronounced as 'hand', 'eat' as 'heat' etc.

Why do they do this?

Comment: I presume from your examples that you are asking about a French accent in English or other languages?

Comment: It's about French people pronouncing English language and these specific words. I'm wondering where these 'h' voices come from.

Comment: Si des français font ça entre eux, alors c'est sans doute pour forcer le trait d'un (supposé) accent étranger. Mais d'habitude, c'est plutôt pour se moquer des allemands.

Comment: I think you are noticing an example of hypercorrection.  The wikipedia article has some interesting examples and discussion (not directly related to your question).  One doesn't really pronounce "h" in French, so two common mistakes in English for a native French speaker are either to drop the "h" sound or to add it everywhere inappropriately out of overcompensation.  I think this is most common if the French speakers are in a community of non-native English speakers (e.g. eurocrats and scientists) -- those I have known who have lived in English speaking countries get over it quickly.

Comment: really they do !?!?!?!

Comment: @Gilles: As edited, the question is clear enough. Now the issue is, "is it on topic?"

Comment: @TomAu the problem I have with this question isn't that the purported behavior is unclear, but that the group of people concerned is unclear. I wasn't sure which close reason to use: “too localized” also applies, because that habit is specific to a few unspecified people (it's not something that I've ever noticed). For this question to make sense, the habit would have to be a documented, widespread one (at least among a particular group of French people).

Comment: I disagree with the "few unspecified people". It is a quite common and well know pronunciation mistake done by many French people. I first noticed it when traveling in the UK with a hungry colleague telling "I want to heat" to a perplexed Englishman. When told how it should be pronounced correctly, he replied it made no difference.

Comment: I suspect this has to do with french phonetics liking so called open syllables, starting with consonants and ending with voyels, and adding *h*es makes these non compliant english syllables closer to easy to pronounce french ones.

Comment: To whoever closed this: the closing of this is inappropriate, I noticed many French speakers do what the author of the question is asking about. Like the word "AirDrop" they will say HairDrop. And often when they wanted to say "angry" , they literally said "hangry" or worse "hungry". I move to recommend reopening of this question.

Comment: @SamuelLisi: Agreed, fully. I can see that with my kids. Until a French person learning English has internalized the discipline of minding the presence and absence of an h at the beginning of a word, except in H, hour, heir, honor, honest and such, they will make many mistakes. It's like learning to mute the k in words beginning with "kn", or to stop pronouncing "of" as if it were "off". It requires conscious effort. In French, the problem of deciding whether an initial "h" is aspiré (and whether to elide and perform liaisons) or not is done purely out of habit.

Answer (score 0):

S'il s'agit de la façon dont les Français prononcent les langues étrangères, il n'y a aucune réponse valable, cela peut dépendre de leur accent régional d'origine, de leur expression orale personnelle, de leur ignorance des usages vernaculaires ou d'autres circonstances.

S'il font ce genre de faute en français, cela devient plus surprenant. Rien n'interdit de poser la question à la personne qui parle ainsi…, ou de la reprendre, si vous êtes certain de connaître la prononciation correcte.

Comment: [Je pense](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3260/why-do-some-french-people-inappropriately-add-an-h-before-english-words-starti#comment6708_3260) qu'il y a des raisons phonétiques "valables", qui ne justifient certes pas, mais qui expliquent.

Comment: @LeVieuxGildas je suis plus en raisonnance avec jlliagre ; il s'agirait plutôt d'un problème d'oreille : dû à un mauvais apprentissage, un manque d'attention, une non connaissance de l'impact sur l'interlocuteur, un peu de paresse intellectuelle, en fait toute ces choses qui nous laisse croire que nous parlons correctement, alors qu'un académicien serait très sourcilleux.

Comment: Problème des commentaires, lire résonance

Comment: À ta place, je supprime le commentaire et le remets sans la faute. Et de temps en temps, ça casse l'ordre de la discussion, et j'en suis désolé. Concernant le sujet, soit, mais ce n'est pas ce que je lis dans ta réponse. (En plus de n'être pas complètement d'accord, cf la réponse que j'aimerais pouvoir poster.)